# Typescript. Optional arguments spreading crashing in v4

Tags: typescript

With TypeScript 3.9+ this construction was working perfectly fine

```js
type keys =
    | 'one'
    | 'another'
    | 'yet_another';

type variables = {
    'another': { count: number }
    'yet_another': { count: number, total: number }
};

export type TFunction = <T extends keys>(
    key: T,
    ...args: T extends keyof variables ? [variables[T]] : []
) => string;
```

Allowing us, to validate arguments passing to the function

```js
t('one');
t('another', {count: 1});
```

But with the latest update to Typescript 4 this construction is not working anymore:

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

t('one');
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    /interfaces.d.ts
...args: T extends keyof variables ? [variables[T]] : [];

Arguments for the rest parameter 'args' were not provided.
```

Any ideas about how to describe it now?

Comment: [Check playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA1hIGcoF4BQUNQD5QOQHsA7CXdTHXAQ0P2AAsIAnUzbPECYAfWtoeYDcqVKEhQAbpUYBLSgCMANhCTIoAbzIYqNek1wAudVADG+AK6FghwmYC2cplAC+m9px47+Bo6YtWoNvZMADRQwLSUCtZ2DozOqE5CqBAAHmD4jMBh4NAAKgBiFsbA0kQoUAA8uVCpwBCEACZIcIgAfAAUri2GucGuAHSDUgDmCD01KXWNzfD4AGYSUrKKylAA-FAA2pIy8koIm7kAukdQhptHqACUKK1QCMAyhMNJpoQPYT2FhMWlhBiqdotUKDfojBA3ZB3DQYRicMyMf64BgKBT4UguETtABERAg2KuQA) I don't get any error... how is `t()` implemented?

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA1hIGcoF4CwAoKUA+UDkA9gHYR4Za54CGRBwAFhAE5mY74gTAD6NdjLANwYMoSFABuVJgEsqAIwA2EJMigBvcvj4NmeAFwaoAYwIBXIsENEzAW3nMoAXy15OPHQINHTFq1Bt7ZgAaKGA6KkVrOwcmZwwnYXQMCAAPMAImYDDwaAAVADELY2AZYhQoAB48qDTgCCIAEyQ4RAA+AAotVsM84K0AOiHpAHMEXtrU+qaW+AIAM0lpOSUVKAB+KABtKVkFZQQtvIBdY6hDLeOMAEoUNqgEYFkiEaTGiGNFaWhTIkew3pFIglMpEJKiDqEEh4a5JYCQzx6ULqEzmSyGACMzlhQA).  And "crashing" implies that the compiler is itself failing to run properly; what's happening to you is just a compiler warning/error.

Comment: True, thx, it runs in pure TS. I'm doing type assignment with JSDoc in .js, will check that.

Comment: Please share the implementation of `t`

Comment: @ExplosionPills it's quite hard to share since it has quite a complex implementation. In short, it could look like:

```js
/** @type {import('./interfaces').TFunction} */
export const t = (key, variables) => key + variables;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the issue. The problem was in typecasting to function that had variables as required.

So TS4 became better in the end, and now catching this.